# Python Inheritance with closures

Tags: python, class, inheritance, closures, overriding

How do I accomplish this kind of inheritance if I have to override or inherit the function2 from class A in class B?

```
class A(object):
    def function1(self, x, y):
        def function2(y):
            print "Function 2 ", y
        print "Function 1 ", x
        function2(y)

class B(A):
    def function1(self, x, y):
        def function2(y):
            print "Before function2"
            # Execute class A function2
            print "After function2"
        # do anything
        return super(B,self).function1(x,y)

a = A()
a.function1(10,6)

b = B()
b.function1(11,7)
```

Comment: There is no "`class A function2`". This is local to method `function1` in class `A` and if you do not externalize this somehow I do not see a way to access it. However, I might oversee something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function2` does not belong to class `A` - it is local to method `function1`. As such, you cannot override or inherit `function2`. If, as your example shows, `function1` does not return a reference to `function2`, then you have no way to access it directly as it *does not actually exist unless `function1` is running*. The only way you can access it is in the way you have already done - by calling `super(B,self).function1`.

However, if `function1` returns a reference to `function2`, then you can use it however you want. For example:

```
class A(object):
    def function1(self, x, y):
        def function2(y):
            print "Function 2 ", y
        print "Function 1 ", x
        return function2
```

By calling `super(B,self).function1(x,y)` you would be returned a reference to `function2`, and you can use it however you want.

---

Let's look at why it doesn't really make sense to talk about overriding or inheriting `function2`. What if `function1` was defined like this:

```
def function1(self, x, y):
    function2 = lambda y: doSomethingWithY(y)
    localVar = 'a local variable'
```

In this case, `function2` is obviously a local variable, as is `localVar`. The lambda syntax for defining a function is more restrictive than using `def <functionname>:`, but the result is the same - a function is created and assigned to a local variable. It makes as much sense to talk about inheriting or overriding `localVar` as for `function2`.

Really, you should be worrying about `function1`. It performs some task based on `x` and `y`, and it is that behavior that you need to be concerned with. It is usually a pretty bad idea to need to worry about exactly how a function accomplishes its task. As you have it above, the function is equivalent to this:

```
def function1(self, x, y):
    print 'Function 1 ', x
    print 'Function 2 ', y
```

If you can make use of the method, then do so. If not, then don't use it. If you want to mask the behavior so that something else happens, then override the method (with the option of calling `super(B,self).function1` if you can use it to help you accomplish the new behavior).

Comment: So there is not a way to modify the behavior of function2 via inheritance because it belongs to funtion1 not precisely class A. If  I need to modify it's behavior I must override completely function1 in class B ore create a new method.